# Using QSharedPointer as Data Model

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer

I have an application with multiple "input widgets" written as inpependent classes, that all store a shared pointer of the respective class that's data thay show. In each of these widgets a user can see and manipulate some different data. All of these data serves as input and also as output of a calculation.
Two of these widgets share the same data/class, but manipulate different members of this class.

How can I achieve that manipulating the data in one widget automaticly updates the other widget?

So the **question** is: Can I share a QSharedPointer between two classes, then connect it to a "this"-slot so that when I manipulate the pointer's value in one of these classes, the other one can do something with this data(as updating it's gui)?

My intention was, since I had to store the actual data in another QSharedPointer, to make a connect on that shared pointer that tells the other widget.

I thought of something like this:

```cpp
#include <QWidget>
#include <QSpinBox>

class MyWidget : QWidget // A template widget to be placed in MainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyWidget()
    {
        this->spinBox = new QSpinBox(this);
        connect(this->spinBox, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, this, &MyWidget::evokedByGuiManipulation);
        connect(this->data.data(), &foo::changed, this, &MyWidget::updateGui);
    }
    virtual ~MyWidget() {delete spinBox;}

public slots:
    void setData(QSharedPointer<foo> value)
    {
        data = value;
    }

    void evokedByGuiManipulation()
    {
        data->manipulate(spinBox->value());
    }

    void updateGui()
    {
        this->spinBox->setValue(data->getData()->datamember);
    }
protected:
    QSharedPointer<foo> data;

private:
    QSpinBox *spinBox;
};
```

**UPDATE**

And class foo is actually a wrapper that stores the actual data `class baz`.
Like:

```cpp
class foo
{
    Q_GADGET
public:
    foo(){}
    QSharedPointer<baz> getData() {return actualData;}

public slots :
    void setActualData(QSharedPointer<baz> value)
    {
        actualData = value;
        emit changed();
    }

signals:
    void changed();

private:
    QSharedPointer<baz> actualData;
};
```

Comment: Aside: you don't need `delete spinBox;`, it is destroyed in the base `~QObject()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming that `foo::manipulate` emits a signal that your other widget connects to.

I would also advise ensuring that `foo::operator=` emit `changed`, so that `setData` updates both widgets.

Not strictly related to your question, there are errors in the code you have shown.

```
connect(this->spinBox, &QSpinBox::editingFinished, this, &MyWidget::evokedByGuiManipulation);
```

`editingFinished` doesn't have a `QSharedPointer<baz>` to pass to `evokedByGuiManipulation`. Did you mean

```
data->manipulate(spinBox->value());
```

Comment: Okay sorry, I didn't clarify my wrapper class `foo` enough.
So here I got the problem that, when I do foo::manipulate I always got a new SharedPointer, so I also had to make a new connection. But what I actually wanted is to manipulate the actual data in place

Comment: *Why* do you have a new `foo` each time, and not a sharing of the same `foo` multiple times?

Comment: Imageine `setData` with new data from the calculation. Now I want to update both the connected widgets at one time instead of setting the new `foo` for both widgets

Comment: Then do `*data = *value;`, and have `foo::operator=` emit `changed`. I'd also change it to `setData(const foo & value)`